# Which employer's address should I indicate on my N-400 Application for Naturalization Form if I worked at different branches over the past few years?

Tags: usa, paperwork, relocation, employment

I worked for the same company but at different locations over the past few years. Which employer's address should I indicate on my  [N-400 Application for Naturalization Form](https://www.uscis.gov/n-400) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200716010951/https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0))?

E.g., the most recent one? The headquarter's address? Shall I add 1 employment period for each different address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branches come and go. Where you worked three years ago may not even exist today.

Enter the current headquarters address of the company. The point of the question is contact info for the company, not to find out where you physically had a desk.